# can i use wild card to monitor particular files in a directory in File::Monitor?

Tags: perl, file, monitor

I am using File::Monitor perl module to notify me about the new/modified files.

Below code snippet is only working for 1.txt input file! where as i would like to monitor for  for all the input files.

I have 2 questions

```
 1-> Does it support wild card such as *.txt?
 2-> Does it monitor recursively ?
```

Here's the code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Monitor;
use File::Monitor::Object;

my @Files=("1.txt","2.txt"); 
my $dir = "C:\\Users\\goudarsh\\Desktop\\Perl_test_scripts";

my $wFileMonitor = File::Monitor->new();
foreach my $wFile (@Files){
my $file = "$dir\\$wFile";
$wFileMonitor->watch($file);
#-- First scan does nothing
$wFileMonitor->scan;

while (1){
  my @changes = $wFileMonitor->scan;
foreach my $object (@changes) {
my $modified = $object->mtime;
  print "$wFile changed\n";
  #fcopy ("$wFile","c:\\newpath");
}
}
}
```

Comment: You never get the the `->watch(...)` call on your second file because of your infinite while loop. Indentation would make this more visible

Comment: @Hunter McMillen Yes you are right! just now i observed this,

Comment: Now my question is how can i get to notify when any *.txt file is created/modified inside my input folder ?

Comment: reading directory is ok! but a folder is created within this input directory and then if any *.txt file is created then ? i want to observed all .txt file inside my input directory

Comment: in the synopsis for File::Monitor they show an example of watching a directory: https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Monitor#SYNOPSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reading directory is ok! but a folder is created within this input
>   directory and then if any *.txt file is created then ? i want to
>   observed all .txt file inside my input directory

There's a `recurse` option you can set for a directory, which will watch for changes in all subdirectories:

```
$monitor->watch( {
    name        => '/Users/7stud/pperl_programs/test_dir/',
    recurse     => 1,
    callback    => {files_created => \&textfile_notifier},  #event => handler
} );
```

Here's a way to track creation of `.txt` files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;

use File::Monitor;
use File::Basename;

sub textfile_notifier {
    my ($watch_name, $event, $change) = @_; 

    my @new_file_paths = $change->files_created; #The change object has a property called files_created, 
                                                 #which contains the names of any new files
    for my $path (@new_file_paths) {
        my ($base, $fname, $ext) = fileparse($path, '.txt'); # $ext is "" if the '.txt' extension is
                                                             # not found, otherwise it's '.txt'.
        if ($ext eq '.txt') {
            say "$path was created";
        }
    }
}

my $monitor = File::Monitor->new();

$monitor->watch( {
    name        => '/Users/7stud/pperl_programs/test_dir/',
    recurse     => 1,
    callback    => {files_created => \&textfile_notifier},  #event => handler
} );

$monitor->scan;

while (1) {
    $monitor->scan;
    sleep(2);
}
```

Listen for modifications to all existing files in a directory; also listen for created files in the directory, and listen for subsequent modifications to the created files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.020;

use File::Monitor;
use File::Basename;
use File::Find;

#Gather all existing .txt files:

my @existing_textfiles;

sub textfiles {
     my ($base, $fname, $ext) = fileparse($File::Find::name, '.txt');

     if ($ext eq '.txt') {
         push @existing_textfiles, $File::Find::name;
     }
}

find(\&textfiles, '/Users/7stud/pperl_programs/test_dir/');
#------------------------------

#Watch for modifications to existing text files:

my $monitor = File::Monitor->new();

for my $existing_textfile (@existing_textfiles) {

    $monitor -> watch( {
            name        => $existing_textfile,
            callback    => { mtime => \&textfile_modified },
    } );

}

sub textfile_modified {
    my ($modified_file) = @_; 
    say "modified: $modified_file";
}
#------------------------------

#Watch for created text files:

$monitor->watch( {
    name        => '/Users/7stud/pperl_programs/test_dir/',
    recurse     => 1,
    callback    => {files_created => \&textfile_created},  
} );

sub textfile_created {
    my ($watch_dir, $event, $change) = @_;

    my @new_files = $change->files_created;

    for my $new_file (@new_files) {
        my ($base, $fname, $ext) = fileparse($new_file, '.txt');

        if ($ext eq '.txt') {
            say "created: $new_file";

            #Watch for moditications to created text files:
            $monitor->watch( {
                    name        => $new_file,
                    callback    => { mtime => \&textfile_modified },
            } );
            #------------------------
        }
    }
}
#---------------------------

$monitor->scan;

while (1) {
    $monitor->scan;
    sleep(2);
}
```

Note that `deleting a file` will show up as a modified file.

Comment: Thanks for the help and i tried to execute this script with my  inputs but it seems not working i do not know where i am doing wrong here are the modified code snippets

_$monitor->watch( {
    name        => 'C:\Users\goudarsh\Desktop\Perl_test_scripts',
    recurse     => 1,
    callback    => {files_created => \&textfile_notifier},  #event => handler
} );_

_my @changes = $monitor->scan;
 for my $change (@changes){
  warn $change->name,"has changed";
 }_

Any idea where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: @Shantesh, 1) Don't post code in comments.  2) All you need to do is copy my script exactly, and replace my directory name with your directory name.

Comment: Sure i will try to improvise my commenting skills and i did tried to copy the exact code and replace the input directory but code seems not working 'coz i can't see anything in the output terminal even if i actually modify any *.txt file in the input directory. btw i am executing this code in windows environment.

Comment: Sad i can't share any screenshots

Comment: @Shantesh, *even if i actually modify any *.txt file in the input director* -- That's because `modifying` =! `creating`.  I responded to your comment, and in your comment the word *modifying* never appeared. If you are interested in knowing when a file is modified, then replace the event `files_created` with the event `mtime`.

Comment: yes you are exactly right ............smart you are! ...i am so dumb :( creating new .txt file did work! any idea on modifying notification ?

Comment: @Shantesh, I have no idea what you are trying to monitor.  It seems you keep changing the target.  If you could clearly state what you are trying to monitor, then we can go from there.

Comment: here is what i am trying to monitor 

At my work different IC design tools generates different logs with '.log' extn and all of  these files are stored in /var/vob/*/project/*/logs/ directory  structure and if any *.log is created then i want read the path and then feed this path as input to some other logic(function) so that it greps some data from required logs and push grepped data into one of database.

Comment: @Shantesh, I posted code that prints the path to any file that is created in a certain directory, *which is now exactly what you claim to want.*

Comment: @Shantesh, See the additional example I posted.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: can i use your code for perl version 5.18.2 ??  'coz say statment does not work in above said version and print does not print any output as well.

Comment: @Shanesh, say() works in all versions of perl after 5.10 -- if you enable it with `use 5.010;` (or later).  say() is just print() with a newline, so you can stick to print(). If the code doesn't work with print(), I can only wonder what OS you are using.

Comment: i was testing your script and found out that if i give input directory as /home/ and create some txt file in /home/goudarsh/desktop/temp_dir/1.txt it did not return me anything! so my question recursive means only 1 folder below the input directory ?

Comment: Yes i was wrong it did work! but it took almost 1min ? how can i do it in real time ?

Comment: @Shantesh, How about trying: `use Time::HiRes qw {usleep};` and in the while loop specifying the number of `microseconds (1 millionth of a second)` that you wish to sleep() between scans: 
`usleep(10_000);`  The Time::HiRes module is a core module, so you don't have to install anything.

Comment: Sorry still not working ! and i have used above mentioned  perl module & i have mentioned only `usleep(10_000);`  within while loop.

Comment: i mean't i am still having the similar effect as i use to have with `sleep(2);`

Comment: sorry to bother you again can i monitor multiple directories ? if yes then how ?

Comment: If you have a lot of files in a lot of different directories, the time it takes to scan them may not be super fast.  Try upping the sleep to: `sleep(10)`.  Any change?  *can i monitor multiple directories*--Identify the section of code that sets up the watch for the directory, copy it, then change the directory name.  You can add as many *watches* to a monitor as you want.